# Есть ли какой-нибудь хороший чат в терминале linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, chat

У меня стоит виндовс 10, там включёна подсистема ubuntu и иногда туда ставлю консольные приложения линукса, так вот есть какой-нибудь хороший чат в терминале ubuntu?

Comment: Есть, называется телеграм: https://github.com/vysheng/tg

Comment: кому/что больше подходит. К примеру, я пользуюсь [erc в emacs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ErcNickNotify#toc4)

Comment: http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/po/po-08.koi#chat

Comment: *irssi* же!    Можно даже больше выжать через протокольные конвертеры.